# creating a static front page

Tags: theming

Please bear with me, I am new to Drupal (I've been adding content for 3 years, now been asked to edit some structural aspects of a site.)

I've been asked to add a static frontpage/homepage to an existing Drupal site with no menus, no headers. This would be a very basic HTML page with an image and 2 links which connect to English and French versions of the main Drupal site.

Is the best way to use a module? I see there is a module called [Front Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/front), but it hasn't been updated in almost 2 years (maybe this is normal?). Is there a more basic way to get a static front page in Drupal, without installing another module?

Also, I am concerned about what will happen to the URL of the current front page if I override it with the Front Page module.

Thank you!

Comment: Check the issue queues - it not having been touched in 2 years might mean it's perfect as it is!

Answer (score 1):

You can add page--front.tpl.php in your enabled theme folder and clear the cache

Comment: thanks for your response! currently, there is currently a page with the  /frontpage path using the Views module.... will that interfere somehow? 
 (sorry, I am a total Drupal noob... stuck in Wordpress world)

Comment: @cejlbot it should still use the template `page--front.tpl.php` don't forget to clear all caches after adding a new template file. Welcome to Drupal btw, hope you enjoy your experience.